# Read JSON float field as integer

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark. I have a data source with JSON objects and that data is being written to Iceberg. The Iceberg schema has `a_field` which is an integer. However, some JSON objects come in with `"a_field": 123.0`, which then results in:

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkRuntimeException:
> [CANNOT_PARSE_JSON_FIELD] Cannot parse the field name 'a_field' and
> the value 123.0 of the JSON token type VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT to target
> Spark data type "INT".

Fixing the data in the source is not easy. Is it possible to "hook" into the Spark JSON parser and demote the float value into an integer value?

Code reproducing the issue.

```
@SneakyThrows
@Test
void test() {
    var schema = new StructType()
        .add(new StructField("a_field", IntegerType$.MODULE$, false, Metadata.empty()))

    var spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .master("local[*]")
        .appName("Java API Demo")
        .getOrCreate();

    String json = """
        {
            "a_field": 123.0
        }
        """;

    Dataset<Row> data = spark.read()
        .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
        .schema(schema)
        .json(spark.createDataset(List.of(json), Encoders.STRING()));

    data.show();
}
```